# Select visible elements into dialog window

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Angular SPA application which is having several dialog windows:

Full code: https://pastebin.com/81ikb5gE

```
<mat-dialog-container aria-modal="true" class="mat-dialog-container ng-tns-c18-93 ng-trigger ng-trigger-dialogContainer ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1" id="mat-dialog-12" role="dialog" style="transform: none;"><!----><mobileweb-inquiry-menu-dialog _nghost-shn-c52="" class="ng-star-inserted"><mobileweb-client-area _ngcontent-shn-c52="" id="clientarea" _nghost-shn-c3="">
.....
</mat-dialog-container>
```

I facing the following issue: Into this dialog I have the same html tag ids. Sometimes I have the same ids 4 times. The application is working fine bug I get always the first id and the rest are not found.

I use this code to open the dialog window:

```
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);
        System.out.println("Click on Button " + name + " using id locator " + buttonId);
        WebElement webDriverElement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(buttonId)));
        webDriverElement.click();
```

Is it possible to isolate the `driver` instance of WebDriver only to the elements of the current active dialog?
For example is it possible to get all elements into the dialog window and cut all of the rest html elements?

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: In case of same `id` you need use another locator, I recomend dynamic xpath. Another approach is work with child elements, methods `findElement(By.by)` and `findElements(By.by)` are applicable to `WebElement` object as well.

Comment: I agree with @pburgr, you can try using other locators.

Comment: Can you show me code example please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/locating-child-nodes-of-webelements-in-selenium

Answer (score 0):

The application is working fine bug I get always the first id and the rest are not found :-

for this issue you can try to use `xpath axes` or `xpath indexing.`

let's say you have a xpath like this  :

```
//input[@class='some-class']
```

that represent 4 items, you can perfrom xpath indexing like this  :

```
(//input[@class='some-class'])[1]
```

or

```
(//input[@class='some-class'])[2]
```

and for this  :

Is it possible to isolate the driver instance of WebDriver only to the elements of the current active dialog? For example is it possible to get all elements into the dialog window and cut all of the rest html elements?

I would say to have a locator that represent that particular model dialogue.

and you can call `getAttribute('innerHTML')` and should represent the particular HTML content.

[Xpath axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)